# String to Entity in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have a LIST of iCal Events that I want to map into an Entity.  The Events are currently in a String and generally have two different formats.

First Format:

```
UID:2a450fcc-a09c-4731-8cd7-8a0a29dca402
SUMMARY:Umpire1: Away Team vs Home Team (Varsity Baseball)
DTSTAMP:20231220T005500Z
DTSTART:20240426T210000Z
DURATION:PT1H
```

Second Format:

```
CLASS:PUBLIC
DTSTART:20221008T130000Z
DTEND:20221008T150000Z
UID:G-66601583
LOCATION: 100 Main St, Springfield OH  44444
DESCRIPTION:Sport: Football
            Level: Freshman
            Team: Home Team
            Site: Home School
            Subsite: Football Field

            John Doe  Position: Football Official
            Mike Smith  Position: Football Official
            Bob Brown  Position: Football Official
```

I want these to map into the class below:

```
public class gameInfo {
    private String uid;
    private String summary;
    private String dtstamp;
    private String dtstart;
    private String dtend;
    private String duration;
    private String location;
    private String description;
```

Ideally that SUMMARY and DESCRIPTION can be broken down to more details.  But really looking for a beginning process to break these down.

Issue seem that this doesn't follow JSON format exactly.  Thinking something with MAPPING or StringSplit.  But haven't been able to research and determine a solution.

Comment: You might need a dedicated iCal format parser for your language. There might be libraries around; I assume your language is c# or java?